# MySQL correlated subquery very slow when range is included

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1N4YYV3wmiWndnZNb95xz/5

For the following tables `nodes` and `leaves`, with `nodes` having just 9 records and `leaves` having a large amount (I inserted ~400k rows just for testing here):

```
> select * from nodes;
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | leaf_left | leaf_right |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |         10 |
|  2 |         1 |          9 |
|  3 |         1 |          8 |
|  4 |         1 |          7 |
|  5 |         1 |          5 |
|  6 |        11 |         20 |
|  7 |        11 |         19 |
|  8 |        11 |         18 |
|  9 |        11 |         17 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

```
> select * from leaves limit 20;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    0 |
|  4 |    0 |
|  5 |    0 |
|  6 |    0 |
|  7 |    0 |
|  8 |    0 |
|  9 |    0 |
| 10 |    0 |
| 11 |    0 |
| 12 |    1 |
| 13 |    0 |
| 14 |    0 |
| 15 |    0 |
| 16 |    0 |
| 17 |    0 |
| 18 |    0 |
| 19 |    1 |
| 20 |    0 |
+----+------+
```

I am attempting to get all `nodes` having a leaf in the range of `[leaf_left, leaf_right]` where `flag = true`.

This query is slow (~0.4 sec):

```
select * from nodes
where exists (
  select 1 from leaves
  where leaves.flag and leaves.id between nodes.leaf_left and nodes.leaf_right
)
```

While this query, which removes the upper limit of the `between` clause, is extremely quick (0.001 sec):

```
select * from nodes
where exists (
  select 1 from leaves
  where leaves.flag and leaves.id > nodes.leaf_left
)
```

The `EXPLAIN` plan for both queries are identical:

```
+------+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type        | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | nodes  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9      | Using where |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | leaves | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 424432 | Using where |
+------+--------------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

So it seems to me that the `between` in the subquery is somehow preventing MySQL from using its index efficiently, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: have you any indexes running. I implemented some tree structures in mysql but it is still slow, because rdms are not really made for it. But without seeing yiour table definitions, this is not possible

Comment: I would expect your query to be a bit quicker on a properly indexed data set, but still, I suspect that something like `SELECT DISTINCT n.* FROM nodes n JOIN leaves l  ON l.id BETWEEN n.leaf_left AND n.leaf_right WHERE l.flag = 1;` would be a bit faster (again assuming proper indexes)

Comment: @Strawberry sorry for the late reply, but I've got a dbfiddle running now: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1N4YYV3wmiWndnZNb95xz/5

Thanks for the link, I'll be sure to use this service in future! As for your `SELECT DISTINCT` suggestion, it does in fact speed up the query - although it's still a bit slower than I would expect for such a small [leaf_left, leaf_right] range. Maybe SQL just doesn't have a good way of querying this schema in the way I want? It's a great improvement though, so if you post an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem multiple times. It looks like MySQL can't use indexes of range selection (aka. BETWEEN) being used in a subquery. The fiddle in this question gives 150ms to execute for nested query, though. This issue is probably fixed in the last MySQL versions.

But e.g. we use the lastest AWS Aurora (MySQL 5.7.12) and a simple nested sets query runs for 2+ sec (!) for just several 10k rows. The fun fact is while you use constants as the boundaries if works just fine and fast:

```
SELECT * FROM nodes
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM leaves
  WHERE leaves.flag AND leaves.id BETWEEN :left AND :right
)
```

It goes down drastically once you use the fields from the outer query. I found a workaround to persuade MySQL the range bondaries are contrants using MySQL variables.

```
SELECT nodes.id,
       @lft := nodes.leaft_left,
       @rgt := nodes.leaf_right
FROM nodes
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM leaves
  WHERE leaves.flag AND leaves.id BETWEEN @lft AND @rgt
)
```

It works as expected. But I couldn't use this as we use Docrine ORM which doesn't understand MySQL variables. But I found the following example works as well:

```
SELECT * FROM nodes
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM leaves
  WHERE leaves.flag AND leaves.id BETWEEN (@lft := nodes.leaf_left) AND (@rht := nodes.leaf_right)
)
```

Looks like a dirty hack but it does what it should do. So I just moved the subquery to a custom DQL function.